# DNN Cookie pop-up not showing - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getVAR')

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

**Update**

I have enabled the DNN (DotNetNuke) Cookie policy setting.

The pop-up won't show unless I have the label tag on a module that is on the page.

**It seems like it will only work when I have a module on a page with a DNN:Label tag.**

```
<dnn:label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="placeholder_label" />
```

I get the following error in the browser console:

[image]

Where it breaks:

[image]

**What can I change in my SKIN file to make this work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is a bug with DNN version 9.04.01, I have upgraded to version 9.10.1 and now it works perfectly.